# How to wait for a bit to set?

Tags: c, stm32

My current implementation looks like this:

```
void send_data(...)
{
    ...
    while(TXE_bit != 1);    /* Wait until TXE_bit becomes 1 */
    ...
}
```

As shown, I am using a while loop to wait until the bit value changes to 1. However, my understanding is that I am using a blocking approach. If the bit never sets, then my code will get stuck in this while loop. So, what is the proper way to do something like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Re "*the bit never sets, then my code will get stuck in this while loop.*", But that's what you said you wanted to do.

Comment: Well, you decide.  If it doesn't get set to 1, under what conditions would you want to give up?  A timeout, or something else?  When you decide what you want, it should become clear how to code it.  But if you want to keep trying indefinitely and never give up, then "getting stuck" is exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh I understand, the lesson would be "If you do not want to get stuck, then implement an exit door. If you do not do that, then be comfortable with getting stuck". Thank you both @NateEldredge and ikegami for your comments, the bit should be set by hardware, I was just concern about the blocking part of the solution.